# Hosting react project (front end and backend) on GitHub

Tags: reactjs, github, github-actions, hosting

I want to deploy my react application on GitHub. I have a confusion while deploying it.

1. Should I deploy both front end and backend separately?
2. When I host the project, how to maintain connection to the MongoDB database I made locally?

Front end : https://github.com/learnfromscratches/connections-frontend.git
Backend : https://github.com/learnfromscratches/Connections-backend.git

I don't have any idea about hosting. How should I host the web site and backend and get it connected?

Answer (score 1):

Github can only deploy static websites, and back -end services should try to deploy on cloud service manufacturers such as Vercel.

Comment: Should i deploy my backend on another hosting platform and add it's link in frontend? and what about my locally created mongoDb database?

Comment: @UnnikrishnanKJ You can try using MongoDB Atlas as your database

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Github Pages as a hosting site, you could only deploy the React part of it (frontend).
To deploy the backend project you should use other sites like Vercel or Render (check https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-deploy-nodejs-application-with-render/) or even AWS or Azure.
As for your database connection you should also deploy it or host it on any of those plaforms (e.g: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sbs/chap-mongodb2documentdb.02.html) and then addd the string connections on your deployed node server.

If you are doing it for testing purposes only I would recommend hosting your apps on separate Docker containers on your local machine, to simulate they are in different machines. Check: https://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/host-multiple-websites-on-docker-containers